# Could not get unknown property 'bundleReleaseAar' Maven Publish

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray, maven-publish

I am trying to publish a library to Bintray, and I am having a problem trying to upload the Aar. I want to use the command `bundleReleaseAar` but unfortunately it does not work for me, I receive the error `Could not get unknown property 'bundleReleaseAar'`. I've researched this problem and I see a lot of answers from around April, that say the solution is to wrap your call in `project.afterEvaluate` however this does not work for me. 
Here is what my code looks like:

```
bintray {
    user = 'dev'
    key = 'asdf'
    publications = ['MyPublication']

    override = true
    publish = true

    pkg {
        repo = 'name of repo'
        name = 'name of package'
        userOrg = 'org'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https//:git.url'
        version {
            name = '0.0.1'
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = '0.0.1'
        }
    }
}

def pomConfig = {
    licenses {
        license {
            name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
            url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
            distribution "repo"
        }
    }
    developers {
        developer {
            id "dev"
            name "dev"
        }
    }

    scm {
        url 'https//:git.url'
    }
}

/***************************************/
/*** THIS IS THE RELEVANT CODE BLOCK ***/
/***************************************/
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
                artifactId 'Artificat Id'
                groupId 'com.group'
                version '0.0.1'

                /****************************/
                /*** WHY DOES THIS CRASH? ***/
                /****************************/
                artifact bundleReleaseAar

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().getAt('dependencies')[0] ?: asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                    configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {

                        if (it.name != 'unspecified') {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                            dependencyNode.children().last() + pomConfig
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had this code in the project level `build.gradle` when it should have been in library modules `build.gradle`. Moving the script here works. I don't know why this solves the problem unfortunately. I can only guess that `bundleReleaseAar` relies on the 'com.android.library' plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `artifact bundleReleaseAar` to work, `bundleReleaseAar` needs to be, as indicated [in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html#org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication:artifact(java.lang.Object)):

- a `PublishArtifact`
- an `AbstractArchiveTask`
- Anything that can resolve to a `File`
- A `Map` with special entries

So you need to figure out what is that `bundleReleaseAar` supposed to be and get it from there.
Assuming it is a task, you could try: `artifact tasks.bundleReleaseAar`